# Div on top of div instead under each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a div that fills the whole width of my website with a gray colour. That's ok. Then I want to fill that div with images but not in the full width. When I try my code, the gray full width div comes first and the div with the images comes just under that one. How can I just place that div on top of that? Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="meerkaas" style="cursor:pointer;" >
                                    <div id="kazensubmenu" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Botermelk</h3>
                                                    <h4>Tijdens het boteren verandert de room naar boterkorrels en botermelk. Deze worden van mekaar gescheiden en zo bekomt men botermelk.</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Yoghurt</h3>
                                                    <h4>wordt gemaakt op basis van gepasteuriseerde melk. We laten de melk verzuren en op een bepaalde temperatuur rusten.
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Vla</h3>
                                                    <h4>meer gekend in Nederland, van kindsaf voor onze 3 zonen de nummer 1 in melkdessertjes, dit kon niet ontbreken in ons assortiment.</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Botermelk</h3>
                                                    <h4>Tijdens het boteren verandert de room naar boterkorrels en botermelk. Deze worden van mekaar gescheiden en zo bekomt men botermelk.</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Yoghurt</h3>
                                                    <h4>wordt gemaakt op basis van gepasteuriseerde melk. We laten de melk verzuren en op een bepaalde temperatuur rusten.
                                                    </h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Vla</h3>
                                                    <h4>meer gekend in Nederland, van kindsaf voor onze 3 zonen de nummer 1 in melkdessertjes, dit kon niet ontbreken in ons assortiment.</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-9.jpg);">
                                            <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                                                <div class="prod-title ">
                                                    <h3>Vla</h3>
                                                    <h4>meer gekend in Nederland, van kindsaf voor onze 3 zonen de nummer 1 in melkdessertjes, dit kon niet ontbreken in ons assortiment.</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#meerkaas {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 650px;
  margin-bottom: 95px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  border: 2px solid white;
}
#kazensubmenu {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: 650px;
  margin-bottom: 95px;
  background: gray;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

NOTE: i know the px is not responsive ok, that's for later..

Comment: postition: absolute; ?

Comment: Why not set the `background-color` of `body` instead of using a `DIV`?

Comment: it's a div that is standard not displayed. only that div should have a background color. Position absolute doesn't t do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will run into big problems when using **vw** in Internet Explorer etc.

This should fix it:

```
#meerkaas {
  background: gray;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#kazensubmenu {
  background: gray;
  left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: an alternative for vw?

Comment: vw and vh arent supported until IE11 and even in IE11 is partial support. I suggest you refer to http://caniuse.com when unsure. If an element is a div it will take 100% width anyways as its a block element. So no need for VW at all

Comment: I tried your code but doesn't give the result: http://1.1m.yt/ppdjJb1.png

Comment: what width do you want to have it? I've added width to the answer. Should work now. By the way, I assume this is for Desktop size viewport right?

Comment: like this but then on top of each other: http://2.1m.yt/AZUdL7J.png
(this is what my code in question results)

Comment: you have 2 times "width: calc(100% - 600px);" in your code?

Comment: Try updated answer now, if doesn't work can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: no, that did the following: http://3.1m.yt/2kWrKw.png
I will now try to make a jsfiddle